# Should I use .pl or .cgi for Perl web script files?

Tags: perl

HI. I created two files 'hello.pl' and 'hello.cgi' with the code below.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";
print "hello world";
```

I can view the page via both 
**http://www.mydomain.com/cgi-bin/hello.pl** 
and **http://www.mydomain.com/cgi-bin/hello.cgi**. 
Which one is more sense in Perl web dev?

BTW, the directory of 'cgi-bin' created by my VPS server, Do I need contact with my VPS support to remove it or just remain it like this URL style? Maybe http://www.mydomain.com/**perDev**/hello.cgi is better?

Comment: Nothing to do with, select which one you like most.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It doesn't really matter which extension you use.  You could configure your server to treat `.potato` as a CGI file if it pleases you.

My personal preference would be to use `.cgi` or even no-extension at all if it will work.  The main reason for that is you give out a bit less information to anyone who may wish to attack your script.  It's a minor thing--**don't rely on this** as a security measure.  This is a chicken-soup security precaution (it can't hurt).

The benefit of not using `.pl` is so slight that you may decide to use `.pl` for the simple fact that it is shorter, and it would still be a good enough reason as far as I am concerned.

Do whatever pleases you.

Comment: An additional reason to avoid `.pl` files is that it is the standard extension used for polish language files for language based content auto negotiation under Apache. That is to say that if you have the files `example.html` and `example.html.pl` Apache can send `example.html.pl` to polish language browsers and `example.html` to other browsers.

Comment: This is wrong. Apache's default configuration since at least 2001 assigns extension `.po` to Polish to avoid exactly the clash you describe.

Comment: Once upon a time, some editors considered .pl to be Prolog programs.

Comment: It should be noted that if the script doesn't set the Content-Type response header properly, it can depend on script extension. No extension would give: text/plain while .cgi would give application/x-cgi. I experienced this with Apache 2.2.222

Answer (score 10):

If at all possible, try to not use extensions, or even exposing real file names if you can. You can do this with apache `mod_rewrite` rules, or a dispatching system with your framework ([Dancer](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Dancer), [CGI::Application](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI::Application::Dispatch), [Catalyst](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Catalyst), etc).

Some do it because it obfuscates things a bit and might provide a bit of extra security (but not much if any). But I do it because it then doesn't tie you down to a particular implementation. What starts out as some simple scripts can turn into a full blown application and people get annoyed if you invalidate their bookmarks. So by picking something abstract you have more freedom to do what you want in the future.

Comment: I also want to learn Perl web framework such as Catalyst, but based on my Php Web dev sense, I would like to learn normal basic .cgi script knowledge & skill, then transfer to dev Perl web app on framework. Thank you.

Comment: @NanoHE Please stop using the dirty old CGI.pm. Use instead a modern and clean web engine such as [Dancer](http://www.perldancer.org/) or [Mojolicious](http://mojolicious.org/).

Answer (score 3):

Mine are usually named .fcgi (I use FastCGI rather than plain CGI), but the user never sees the program's name thanks to a bit of URL rewriting in .htaccess.  It's much nicer for users to be able to just go to http://mysite.com/ instead of http://mysite.com/mycode.fcgi, after all.

Functionally, it's identical regardless of extension.  As daotoad said, the server can be configured to recognize that something is a CGI executable based on any file extension you choose, or by its location in the file system (sites using a /cgi-bin/ directory will usually treat everything in that directory as a CGI program regardless of name or extension), or even individually-named files with no apparent pattern or connection between them.

Answer (score 3):

Use either no extension or something generic like .cgi.

daotoad is correct about .pl being a minor security leak, but more importantly it pegs your URLs to your current implementation language.  URLs should be a permanent location for information.  Should you decide in the future to rewrite your application later in another language you'll be stuck with the legacy .pl extension.

The same applies for command line programs.  Just write `command` not `command.pl` and let the `#!` line do its job.  After all, we don't run `ls.c`.

mpeters is also correct in that you should avoid linking your URLs to actual files, again not so much for security purposes but to make the URL a permanent interface.  For example, you want `http://example.com/login` not `http://example.com/cgi-bin/login`.

Answer (score 2):

All other things being equal, I'd name it `.cgi` to remind the coder that it is not just another Perl script and has robustness requirements special to CGI.

Answer (score 2):

Use **none**.

[Because URLs should be meaningful and technology independent](http://coi.gov.uk/guidance.php?page=270).

Modern Perl web frameworks such as [Dancer](http://www.perldancer.org/) or [Mojolicious](http://mojolicious.org/) can help you to achieve that.